# Comparing char array elements

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, char, bubble-sort

I'm trying to arrange this character array that only contains digits,it prints the same array with the order I input it without any change , i tried using type casting in the if statement, it gave me correct results when running but it wasn't accepted by the online judge.what is the fault here and why isn't my second solution accepted?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char x[101];
    scanf("%s",x);
    int l,i,j ;

    l = strlen(x);

    char temp ;

    for(i=0;x[i];i++)
    {
        for( j=i ; x[j] ; j++){

            if('x[j]'<'x[i]') //(int)x[j] and (int)x[i] didn't work on the 
                               //online judge
            {
                temp=x[i];
                x[i]=x[j];
                x[j]=temp;

            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s",x);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What is this `'x[j]'`? it's a multicharacter constant and very likely is not doing what you want. Also, `l = strlen(x);` and the you drop `l`, remove that.

Comment: I thought it changes the character to an integer representing the ascii of this character like stated her http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_chars.html so I can compare them.can you elaborate?

Comment: @OmarKhaled By all means you can, but it makes no sense. Since these are constant strings, it's pretty much equivalent to `if(false)` in this case.

Comment: @szczurcio I don't think it's possible to ensure that it will be `if (false)`, because the value is implementation defined, so there could exist in theory a compiler where it's `if (true)`.

Comment: @iharob Yup, you're right, I just based my comment on what it was in my case. Point was that the value is constant, so checking it makes no sense.

Comment: @OmarKhaled It doesn't, a character constant gives the ascii value of the character, but that is for single characters, multiple characters give an integer too, but not the ascii value of anything, since ascii values make sense only for characters not for strnigs. And the byte value stored in the array is almost for sure, the ascii value of the character they represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why there are quotes around the array elements, but that is not doing what you think, the comparison is happening because a multicharacter string is evaluated to an integer value which is implementation defined, hence the if statement is **always comparing the same values**, which means that it will always give the same result, you need to remove the quotes

```
if (x[j] < x[i])
```

Also, i'd recommend specifying the length of the array to `scanf()` and checking that it successfuly read the value, like this

```
if (scanf("%100s", x) != 1)
    return -1; /* Perhaps EOF, i.e. you pressed Ctrl+D or (Ctrl+Z MS Windows) */
```

If you don't check your program will invoke undefined behavior, and if here it doesn't hurt any critical part of your simple program, if you don't learn to do it, then you will have a lot of hard do debug bugs in the future when you write a bigger program.

Comment: Well, this code is for an online judge problem, so while such a check is a good practice, in this case it'd be a waste of time since no one will give that code invalid input.

Comment: @OmarKhaled you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark, I hope you understood my explanation, otherwise please feel free to request clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes in your `if` statement evaluate to multicharacter constants, which in my compiler (VC++ 2013) happen to be `785B6A5D` and `785B695D` respectively, which are the ASCII codes of these characters glued together. Thus that `if` never executes. Also, what do you mean by "didn't work"? Did you get a compilation error? If yes, what did it say? Otherwise you may have exceeded the time limit since bubble sort is extremely slow.

Comment: No I get wrong answer from test number 1 the judge's compiler returns output from my code that is different from my compiler in the sample test case even after I made the correction you told me about